# Change php configuration file in PhpStorm

Tags: php, wamp, phpstorm

I have installed WAMP server on my computer and tried to configure the PHP Interpreter in PhpStorm but it keeps pointing to the wrong `php.ini` file.

How can I change it to the correct one?

Let me know if you need more information.

---

**Edit**

[image]

The place where php.ini that WAMP tells me to edit is `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin\php.ini`

The one that PhpStorm is pointing to has a big DO NOT EDIT label on it.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/configuring-local-php-interpreters.html

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"? Show screenshots -- what it detects and what it should be instead (and why)? PhpStorm just launches your configured interpreter (the file you have specified) and then just gets info from its' output. In other words -- it's PHP itself that informs PhpStorm what php.ini it uses. But yes -- there is no option in IDE to tell that PHP Interpreter should be launched with another (custom) php.ini.

Comment: Please use `@username` otherwise there will be no notification for new messages/comments.

Comment: Regarding your issue: everything is correct here. PHP Interpreter is meant to be used in **CLI environment** -- it is used for running PHPUnit tests, CodeSniffer/MessDetector integration; Composer/Phing integration as well as executing and debugging your scripts in CLI environment and alike. You do not need any PHP Interpreter if you will be debugging your code via browser .. **as IDE simply will NOT use it** (as it's used by actual web server (**Apache** in your case) **directly**).

Comment: If you execute your `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.0\php.exe` in terminal with `-i` parameter  -- you will see what config file it uses (in first 10 or so lines). PhpStorm just reads that info. Then you can compare to what WAMP (Apache) uses by checking `phpinfo()` output -- same field from top table.

Comment: So .. if you need to use PHP Interpreter in CLI mode (see my previous comment) .. then you have 2 choices: **1)** actually edit that php.ini (quite possibly that some settings are loaded from additional .ini files -- check corresponding field from `php -i` or `phpinfo()` output -- you may edit them instead) **2)** create custom PHP installation yourself (download from windows.php.net site; install it elsewhere (e.g. `C:\PHP`) and configure it as you require) -- it will use different php.ini (e.g. `C:\PHP\php.ini`).

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a website you are attempting to write then you need to point your `Configuration File` at

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin\php.ini
```

> **NOTE**
>
> There are PHP ADDONS provided for PHP7 that will install into the existing WAMPServer 3.0.x and the latest is PHP7.0.8 [found here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) or from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/Addons/Php/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I backed up the original `php.ini` content inside `bin\php\php7.0xxx` folder, and I replaced the content with the `php.ini` inside `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin\php.ini`, and then restarted phpstorm and it worked.